# google+ oAuth contacts full list in PHP

Tags: php, oauth, google-plus

i am using googles latest api to retrieve the contact list.  This code seems to output in XML the first 20 items of my list.
Question: how can i output the entire list?

```
<?php
require_once '../../src/apiClient.php';
session_start();

$client = new apiClient();
$client->setApplicationName('Google Contacts PHP Sample');
$client->setScopes("http://www.google.com/m8/feeds/");
// Documentation: http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/docs/2.0/basics.html
// Visit https://code.google.com/apis/console?api=contacts to generate your
// oauth2_client_id, oauth2_client_secret, and register your oauth2_redirect_uri.
// $client->setClientId('insert_your_oauth2_client_id');
// $client->setClientSecret('insert_your_oauth2_client_secret');
// $client->setRedirectUri('insert_your_redirect_uri');
// $client->setDeveloperKey('insert_your_developer_key');

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $client->authenticate();
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
    $redirect = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}

if (isset($_SESSION['token'])) {
 $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['token']);
}

if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['token']);
    $client->revokeToken();
}

if ($client->getAccessToken()) {
    $req = new apiHttpRequest("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full");
    $val = $client->getIo()->authenticatedRequest($req);

    // The contacts api only returns XML responses.
    /* * * * * * * * * produced an error
    $response = json_encode(simplexml_load_string($val->getResponseBody()));
    print "<pre>" . print_r(json_decode($response, true), true) . "</pre>"; 
    */

    // fix
    $response = $val->getResponseBody();
    print "<pre>" . print_r($response) . "</pre>";


    // The access token may have been updated lazily.
    $_SESSION['token'] = $client->getAccessToken();
} else {
    $auth = $client->createAuthUrl();
}

if (isset($auth)) {
        print "<a class=login href='$auth'>Connect Me!</a>";
    } else {
        print "<a class=logout href='?logout'>Logout</a>";
}
?>
```

i saw this [response](http://groups.google.com/group/google-contacts-api/tree/browse_frm/month/2012-05/4ea69e52ae930044?rnum=51&lnk=nl) , but have no idea how to implement it


*Firstly you need to ask for version 3 as the extendedProperties are
not returned. Here's a c-n-p from some working code.*

```
function get($xmlfile) {
try {
  @$feed = simplexml_load_file($xmlfile. '&v=3.0');
  if ($feed === FALSE) {
    throw new Exception(file_get_contents($xmlfile));
  }
} catch (Exception $e) {
  return array('error' => true, 'payload' => $e->getMessage());
}
return array('error' => false, 'payload' => $xmlData);
}
```

*Next thing to look for is something to tell simplexml that you want to
use the gd namespace. Another example:*

```
 $this->nsGd = $xmlData->children('http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');
 ...
 $this->email = @(string)$this->nsGd->email->attributes()->address;
 ...
 foreach ($this->nsGd->extendedProperty as $x) {
    if ($x->attributes()->name == 'ethnicity') {
      $this->ethnicity = $x->attributes()->value;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using the max-results query parameter? From the [Contacts API documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/).

> **Note**: The feed may not contain all of the user's contacts, because there's a default limit on the number of results returned. For more
>   information, see the max-results query parameter in [Retrieving
>   contacts using query parameters](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_contacts_using_query_parameters).

So, you could send a request such as: https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?max-results=1000

Comment: i feel there is conflicting answers because it says `To retrieve all of a user's contacts, send an authorized GET request to the following URL:`  but then it says that there might be limits

Comment: The request defaults to a max_results of 25. If you add in the max_results parameter, you can override it. I tried it with one of my Google accounts and retrieved 282 contacts at one time.